# Python: Create a matrix of the length of the intersection of two lists whose elements are sets of numbers

Tags: python, matrix, set, matrix-multiplication, set-intersection

I'm using Python 3.5 and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

- I have two lists (`list1` and `list2`).
- Each element in each list is a `set` of numbers.
- In the example below, `list1` is basically a 1x4 "matrix" and `list2` is a 1x3 "matrix".
- I want to make a 4x3 matrix that gives the ***length*** of the intersection of each element in `list1` with each element in `list2`

Here is some sample code that works, but it's somewhat slow when the length of my lists is in the thousands.

Is there a faster/better way??

Thank you!

```
list1 = [{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {1,2,9}, {4,5,10}] # 1 x 4 "matrix"
list2 = [{1,3,9}, {4,2,8}, {1,0,10}] # 1 x 3 "matrix"

myoutputmatrix = []

for aset in list1:
    small_list = [len(aset & asecondset) for asecondset in list2]
    myoutputmatrix .append(small_list)

myoutputmatrix # [[2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: What you have already looks like the most efficient way to do it synchronously.  Consider using multiprocessing to parallelize, if you need it faster.

Comment: Try using `numpy` it has numerous functions for manipulation of matrices

Comment: micro-optimization: `myoutputmatrix = [[len(l1 & l2) for l2 in list2] for l1 in list1]`. Though you're expecting something more considerable in timings, I suppose

Comment: This is actually straight-up matrix multiplication, once you convert the inputs into actual matrices where a `1` indicates the presence of a particular number in a particular input set and a `0` indicates absence.

Comment: @user2357112 I hadn't thought about it that way, but you're right. It may be worth it to transform each set into a "full" vector. Maybe that's faster. Thanks.

Comment: For the matrix multiplication, get [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). It'll be way faster than anything you could write by hand in pure Python. If the matrices are sparse, consider the sparse matrix types in [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).